# how to save a value inside a loop and add on it variables?

Tags: python, loops, iteration, save

I will be more specific: what I ask is how can I have a loop that saves its output every iteration and thus on every next iteration the loop does adds a value on the existing output, then it saves this too and repeat. for me, this is relevant for my tic tac toe I am building, which consist of a string that I desire to add on it variables (in this case a player who is either "x" or "o") afterwards, it needs to be saved. when additing another variable it should be shown in the same "board" that contains the previous variable. the problem here is, that I don't know how to do such saving action and then add on the SAME string another variable.

```
   def board(player, position):
     def saving():
    
      for i in range(1,9): 
       if position == i:
          posi = ["nothing","-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-"]
          posi[i] = player
          set1 = f"{posi[1]} | {posi[2]} | {posi[3]}\n"
          set2 = f"{posi[4]} | {posi[5]} | {posi[6]}\n"
          set3 = f"{posi[7]} | {posi[8]} | {posi[9]}\n"
          return set1, set2, set3
          continue 
     print1,_,_=saving()
     _,print2,_=saving()
     _,_,print3=saving()
     print(print1)
     print(print2)
     print(print3)
```

actually I am unfamiliar with what specific function can do a saving action. thus I had tried to play with list because I noticed that it appears in scripts that have such action. I tried to add on "continue" to see wether that gives the saving action. both didn't work. I will add that for clarity, regarding the given script, the "position" is an int that can only be in the range of 1-9, while "player" is a string that is x or o.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Could you provide an example of what you want your code to do? i.e., the correct output given some player and position

Comment: surely. in the context of tic tac toe, the goal of ths script is to get the user output and add it accordingly to the "GUI"-the tic tac toe board. how it works is by that the user gives the mark he is which is "o" or "x", and the position he wants to locate his mark. in this case, the "player" is for mark, and "position" is for the position. now the poisition is identified by numbers from 1-9 (top left is 1, bottom right is 9 on the board).

Comment: Now, the PROBLEM here is.. when additing the player sign, I also need to add another one. not only that, it needs to be shown in the same board with the previous outputs. after analyzing on such thing should work, I concluded that the board with the new mark needs to be saved in some way, inorder for making additing another mark. I don't know how to save it.

Comment: @jhschwartz this is the extended explaination.

Comment: I think I understand - you are able to record the first move of a game of tic-tac-toe with the function `board` as-is. But you would like be able to record the second move, the third move, etc. upon the same board. Is that correct?

If so, then I can help you. I get the feeling, though, that this might be for a class assignment, right? Unfortunately, your code is a bit poorly organized as-is and I would have to pretty much rewrite it to fix it. I don't want to do your homework for you. Instead, I'll lay out a couple steps I would take to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make updates upon the same grid, you'll want to save that grid as a variable outside your function and make updates to the grid using the `board` (`record_move` below) function.

Additionally, I encourage you to make use of nested lists to represent your grid. Given a nested list, we can access the upper-right corner with `game_grid[0][0]`, the middle as `game_grid[1][1]`, and so on. I know you had indices 1-9 but it is customary in most programming languages (including python) to begin counting at zero. I'm going to use 0-indexing from this point forward.

And, also, I think we should rename some of your variables and function for clarity. I'll call the function that records moves `record_move` instead of `board`. I'll call the 'x' or the 'o' that a player chooses `move` instead of `player`. And, lastly, I'll call the position `position` just like before.

So your script would look something like:

```
def record_move(move, position, game_grid):
    # implementation here


game_grid = [["-","-","-"], ["-","-","-"], ["-","-","-"]]

# Now, here, you can do something with game_grid. 
# Perhaps you want to prompt the user for input within a while loop.
# That's a relatively common procedure that you can search for elsewhere.
# But the main point is that now you can use the function board(...) to 
# make updates to the same game_grid.
```

Ok, onto the implementation of `record_move` itself. You only need one function, not two.

For the first two lines of your function, recall that you can set a location i,j of a nested list with `game_grid[I][j] = VALUE`. We can convert from `position` to two coordinates by doing something like

```
i = position // 3 # "a // b" gives us the floor of "a/b", so for example 4 // 3 = 1
j = position % 3 # "a % b" gives us the remainder of "a/b" so for example 4 % 3 is 1
```

Test it yourself and you will see that this lets you convert all 9 positions (numbered 0-8) to coordinates.

For the third line of your function, you simply need to set `game_grid` at coordinate `i,j` to `move`.

In the fourth line just return `game_grid`.

That should set you up to solve your issue. If you really want to stick to 1-indexing, just subtract 1 from position before doing the calculations in your function's lines 1 and 2.

Lastly, this task would be well-suited by object oriented programming. If you have any experience with that, I suggest instead representing the entire grid as a class and making the `record_move` function a member of that class.

Comment: I forgot to include converting to the printing form you were using with `|` and such. I'll leave that up to you to add on.